# In .NET, which loop runs faster, 'for' or 'foreach'?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, for-loop

In `C#/VB.NET/.NET,` which loop runs faster, `for` or `foreach`?

Ever since I read that a `for` loop works faster than a `foreach` loop a [long time ago](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973839(v=msdn.10)) I assumed it stood true for all collections, `generic collections`, all `arrays`, etc.

I scoured Google and found a few articles, but most of them are inconclusive (read comments on the articles) and open ended.

What would be ideal is to have each scenario listed and the best solution for the same.

For example (just an example of how it should be):

1. for iterating an `array` of 1000+
   strings - `for` is better than `foreach`
2. for iterating over `IList` (non generic) strings - `foreach` is better
   than `for`

A few references found on the web for the same:

1. [Original grand old article by  Emmanuel Schanzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973839(v=msdn.10))
2. [CodeProject FOREACH Vs. FOR](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/foreach.aspx)
3. [Blog - To `foreach` or not to `foreach`, that is the question](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/kevin_ransom/to-foreach-or-not-to-foreach-that-is-the-question)
4. [ASP.NET forum - NET 1.1 C# `for` vs `foreach`](https://web.archive.org/web/20100123104946/http://weblogs.asp.net/mdavey/archive/2004/02/25/79504.aspx)

[Edit]

Apart from the readability aspect of it, I am really interested in facts and figures. There are applications where the last mile of performance optimization squeezed do matter.

Comment: The difference still exists. Arrays in particular should be just as fast under foreach, but for everything else, plain loops are faster. Of course, most of the time, this won't make a difference, and of course, a clever JIT compiler could in theory eliminate the difference.

Comment: I see three solutions: (1) Write a compiler that enumerates in random order (2) rename "foreach" to "ForEachInStrictOrder (3) Rename ourselves to ~Ian perhaps Iain?

Comment: In general for would be faster then foreach. However if you care you've probably got "other problems" which are of higher importance...

Comment: Without context, I can't know exactly what you're doing, but what happens when you come across a partially filled array?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723855/ienumerable-question-best-performance/1724054#1724054

Comment: What I have learned from posting my thread (which ended up being a very beneficial insight for me) is that you should use a foreach when you don't need to reference an index in the collection. Otherwise use a for. That's one good decision point

Comment: Related [Performance difference for control structures 'for' and 'foreach' in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124753/performance-difference-for-control-structures-for-and-foreach-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 451, accepted):

Patrick Smacchia [blogged about this](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/11/19/an-easy-and-efficient-way-to-improve-net-code-performances.aspx) last month, with the following conclusions:

> - for loops on List are a bit more than 2 times cheaper than foreach
>     loops on List.
> - Looping on array is around 2 times cheaper than looping on List.
> - As a consequence, looping on array using for is 5 times cheaper
>     than looping on List using foreach
>     (which I believe, is what we all do).

Comment: However, never forget: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: @Hardwareguy: Once you know that for is almost imperceptably faster, why shouldn't you start using it in general? It doesn't take extra time.

Comment: @devinb,  using "for" is harder than using "foreach" as it adds code, another variable, a condition you need to check, etc.  How many times have you seen an off-by-one error in a "foreach" loop?

Comment: @Hardwareguy, let me see if I got this straight. It takes 5 times longer to loop through a list with `foreach` than it does to loop through an array with `for`, and you're calling that insignificant? That kind of a performance difference might matter for your application, and it might not, but I wouldn't just dismiss it out of hand.

Comment: Reading through the blog post it looks like the tests were run in Debug and not Release so that might have a factor.  Additionally the difference is specifically for just the loop overhead.  It doesn't affect the time to execute the body of the loop at all which is most cases is much longer than the time it takes to move to the next element of the list.  It's good information to know when you've identified that there clearly is a problem and you've measured the difference in your app specifically and there's a noticeable improvement but definitely not general advice to remove all `foreach`s.

Comment: `foreach` can be way cheaper then `for loop` with `LinkedList`

Comment: the images within that link are broken, here's the archived copy http://web.archive.org/web/20140827024150/http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/11/19/an-easy-and-efficient-way-to-improve-net-code-performances/

Comment: @Davy8 I have check current results in release mode using Stopwatch.
The results have changed since that article was written.

1. List<int> loop is almost 7 times faster than foreach loop. 100 000 000^2 iterations were performed. For with optimized count is the fastest, but the is almost no difference with the example without optimization (for no optimization: 326; for count optimized: 296; foreach 2356).
2. But, what is more interesting. In some cases for a int[] foreach is a little faster than for (for no optimization: 294; for count optimized: 294; foreach 267, less!). 10^8^2 opers as well.

Comment: @gdoron I know you were referring to including an index lookup, but a `for (n = l.First; n != null; n = n.Next)` loop is about halfway between a `foreach` loop and the corresponding array-based `for`loop.

Comment: can't you replace cheaper with faster(if that's what you mean). it'd be clearer

Comment: @Ian Nelson: In jacksondunstan article, ForEach - Assignment is not done . I had change the code and executed as you mentioned the results was not changed... Thanks :-0)

Comment: Is it worth adding a qualifier on this answer; i.e. switching from `foreach` on a list  to `for` on an array will not (in most cases) improve your code's performance by 5x as implied.  If all you were doing was looping that would be true, but then you could improve performance infinitely by skipping the loop altogether.  If you have code within the loop, that will still take just as long to process, and will still process once per iteration , typically making the benefit of the `for` loop fairly negligible by comparison.

Comment: If the figures are accurate, it's a compiler problem and it can be fixed at that level. I think the ease of use is more important. If it is not some extremely hot path in code, no one should care.

Comment: want to say something, when you work on mobile, and when you find your heap suffer, and you getting crashed due to memory framgentation, check how many foreach you have.

Foreach allocate memory and cause GC too, so its not Premature optimization evil here.

Comment: Because it's fun to add anecdotal info years after a post...I have been optimizing a serious amount of iterating in some methods that run in Azure functions (500K-1.5M items, multiple passes & lookups into the same list). FOR has resulted in better perf 100% of the time. Even assigning to a local var (var item = list[i];) has resulted in an instant performance improvement. There have been other tricks for the needed perf bump (parallel, hash sets, lookups - a combination of everything based on the very specific need in that specific code), but FOR (IME) is faster. Period.

Comment: Just something to note, from Concurrency in C# Cookbook by Stephen Cleary: "A foreach loop over an ImmutableList<T> executes in O(N) time, while a for loop over the same collection executes in O(N*logN) time." Same thing with an ImmutableSortedSet<T>.

Comment: This answer may have been right 14 years ago, but I think the gap has significantly closed. I get a 30% different on lists and a 50% difference on arrays.

Answer (score 188):

First, a counter-claim to [Dmitry's (now deleted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/472200). For arrays, the C# compiler emits largely the same code for `foreach` as it would for an equivalent `for` loop. That explains why for this benchmark, the results are basically the same:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    const int Size = 1000000;
    const int Iterations = 10000;

    static void Main()
    {
        double[] data = new double[Size];
        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = rng.NextDouble();
        }

        double correctSum = data.Sum();

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i=0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int j=0; j < data.Length; j++)
            {
                sum += data[j];
            }
            if (Math.Abs(sum-correctSum) > 0.1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Summation failed");
                return;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("For loop: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i=0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            foreach (double d in data)
            {
                sum += d;
            }
            if (Math.Abs(sum-correctSum) > 0.1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Summation failed");
                return;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Foreach loop: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
For loop: 16638
Foreach loop: 16529
```

Next, validation that Greg's point about the collection type being important - change the array to a `List<double>` in the above, and you get radically different results. Not only is it significantly slower in general, but foreach becomes significantly slower than accessing by index. Having said that, I would still *almost always* prefer foreach to a for loop where it makes the code simpler - because readability is almost always important, whereas micro-optimisation rarely is.

Comment: "change the array to a List<double> in the above, and you get radically different results" Very interesting, I hadn't thought about that

Comment: Given the strange differences in results between my tests and other people's benchmarks, I think this is going to merit a blog post...

Comment: Which do you *almost always* prefer between arrays and `List<T>`? Does readability trump micro-optimization in that case too?

Comment: @JohnB: Yup - I almost always prefer `List<T>` over arrays. The exceptions are `char[]` and `byte[]` which are more often treated as "chunks" of data rather than normal collections.

Comment: Amazing, I'm getting even more aggressive difference on my machine, almost 10% in favor of foreach on simple arrays. I'm guessing wildly that this all stems from the jitter not have to worry about the extra variable, bound checks, etc.. would be very interesting if someone has a deep explanation of this.

Comment: What is the reason that using a `List<double>` or any in a foreach becomes slower? Would converting the list to an array before the foreach do anything, or is that just a waste of memory? Would the same apply to an `IEnumerable<double>`?

Comment: @Adjit: I don't know whether I looked into that at the time (bear in mind this was over 13 years ago) - but I wouldn't be at all surprised to find that things have changed a lot in the meantime. Moral of the story: always measure.

Answer (score 169):

**`foreach` loops demonstrate more specific intent than `for` loops**.

Using a `foreach` loop demonstrates to anyone using your code that you are planning to do something to each member of a collection irrespective of its place in the collection. It also shows you aren't modifying the original collection (and throws an exception if you try to).

The other advantage of `foreach` is that it works on any `IEnumerable`, where as `for` only makes sense for `IList`, where each element actually has an index.

However, if you need to use the index of an element, then of course you should be allowed to use a `for` loop. But if you don't need to use an index, having one is just cluttering your code.

There are no significant performance implications as far as I'm aware. At some stage in the future it might be easier to adapt code using `foreach` to run on multiple cores, but that's not something to worry about right now.

Comment: This is very helpful when iterating through a custom object list or datalist and not have to worry about all the index nomenclature when processing the data.

Comment: I can't see how `foreach` helps multithreading. I guess you are referring to things like Task Parallel Library but that's not really a magic of `foreach`.

Comment: @Mehrdad The compiler has freedom on how to iterate through the list with foreach. For example, it could iterate through the the even elements on one core and the odd elements on another.

foreach is closer to the functional style of programming.

Comment: ctford: No it's not. The compiler certainly cannot reorder elements in `foreach`. `foreach` is not at all related to functional programming. It's **totally** an imperative paradigm of programming. You are mis-attributing things happening in TPL and PLINQ to `foreach`.

Comment: @Mehrdad,ctford: I guess it depends if foreach has a guarantee of order. If foreach has no guarantee of order it could be optimized by a future version of the compiler to use the cores if there is something like an attribute to mark the code within the foreach loop as thread-safe ?

Comment: @BlueTrin: It certainly does guarantee ordering (C# spec section 8.8.4 formally defines `foreach` as an equivalent of a `while` loop). I think I know @ctford is referring to. Task parallel library allows **the underlying collection** to provide elements in an arbitrary order (by calling `.AsParallel` on an enumerable). `foreach` doesn't do anything here and the body of the loop is executed on a **single thread**. The only thing that is parallelized is the generation of the sequence.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Also, using foreach helps to avoid coupling your element processing code with any concept of ordering, thus making it more easily paralisable in the future. I overstated my point - foreach is not map.

Comment: `foreach` actually works with any IEnumerable-"like" object (not a correction to your post as much as an interesting note about duck typing): http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2007/07/18/DuckNotation.aspx

Comment: Enumerable.Select has an overload that lets you obtain the index of the item, so even the need for an index does not mandate using for. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx

Comment: ForEach is handy for readability and saving typing. Costs matter, though; changing 2 or 3 for-loops in a document designer UI that I made, from (for each obj in list) to (for i=0 to list.count-1) reduced response time from 2-3 sec per edit to about .5 sec per edit on a small document just looping thru a few hundred objects. Now for even huge documents, there is no increase in time to loop all. I have no idea how this happened. What I do know is that the alternative was a complicated scheme to only loop a subset of the objects. I'll take the 5 minute change any day! - _not_ micro-optimisation.

Comment: @FastAl The difference between `foreach` and `for` performance for normal lists is fractions of a second for iterating over millions of items so your issue certainly wasn't directly related to foreach performance, at least not for a few hundred objects. Sounds like a broken enumerator implementation in whatever list you were using.

Answer (score 55):

It will always be close. For an array, *sometimes* `for` is slightly quicker, but `foreach` is more expressive, and offers LINQ, etc. In general, stick with `foreach`.

Additionally, `foreach` may be optimised in some scenarios. For example, a linked list might be terrible by indexer, but it might be quick by `foreach`. Actually, the standard `LinkedList<T>` doesn't even offer an indexer for this reason.

Comment: So are you saying `LinkedList<T>` is leaner than `List<T>`? And if I'm always going to be using `foreach` (instead of `for`), I'm better off using `LinkedList<T>`?

Comment: @JohnB - not leaner; just different. For example, each node in a linked list has additional references that aren't needed for a flat array (which also underpins `List<T>`). It is more that it is cheaper to *insert* / *remove*.

Answer (score 54):

Any time there's arguments over performance, you just need to write a small test so that you can use quantitative results to support your case.

Use the StopWatch class and repeat something a few million times, for accuracy. (This might be hard without a for loop):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
//...
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch()
sw.Start()
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000;i ++)
{
    //do whatever it is you need to time
}
sw.Stop();
//print out sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

Fingers crossed the results of this show that the difference is negligible, and you might as well just do whatever results in the most maintainable code

Comment: But you can't compare performance of for and foreach. They are supposed to be used in different circumstances.

Comment: I agree with you Michael, you shouldn't choose which one to use based on performance - you should choose the one that makes the most sense! But if your boss says "Don't use for because it's slower than foreach" then this is the only way to convince him that the difference is negligible

Comment: "(This might be hard without a for loop)" Or you can use a while loop.

Answer (score 39):

My guess is that it will probably not be significant in 99% of the cases, so why would you choose the faster instead of the most appropriate (as in easiest to understand/maintain)?

Comment: @klew, If you actually profile your code you wouldn't have to guess which 20% need to be as fast as possible.  You would probably also find out that the actual number of loops which need to be fast is much lower.  Furthermore, are you really saying that the act of looping is where you spend your time, as opposed to what you actually do in that loop?

Answer (score 34):

There are very good reasons to **prefer** `foreach` loops over `for` loops. If you can use a `foreach` loop, your boss is right that you should.

However, not every iteration is simply going through a list in order one by one. If he is *forbidding* for, yes that is wrong.

If I were you, what I would do is **turn all of your natural for loops into recursion**. That'd teach him, and it's also a good mental exercise for you.

Comment: How does recursion compare to `for` loops and `foreach` loops performance-wise?

Comment: It depends. If you use tail-recursion and your compiler is smart enough to notice, it can be identical. OTOH: If it doesn't and you do something stupid like pass a lot of unnessecary (unchanging) data as parameters or declare big structures on the stack as locals, it can be really really slow (or even run out of RAM).

Comment: Ahhh. I see why you asked that now. This answer went to a totally different question. For some bizzare reason Jonathan Sampson merged the two yesterday. He really shouldn't have done that. The merged answers will make no sense here whatsoever.

Answer (score 32):

There is unlikely to be a huge performance difference between the two. As always, when faced with a "which is faster?" question, you should always think "I can measure this."

Write two loops that do the same thing in the body of the loop, execute and time them both, and see what the difference in speed is. Do this with both an almost-empty body, and a loop body similar to what you'll actually be doing. Also try it with the collection type that you're using, because different types of collections can have different performance characteristics.

Answer (score 21):

Jeffrey Richter on TechEd 2005:

> "I have come to learn over the years the C# compiler is basically a liar to me." .. "It lies about many things." .. "Like when you do a foreach loop..." .. "...that is one little line of code that you write, but what the C# compiler spits out in order to do that it's phenomenal. It puts out a try/finally block in there, inside the finally block it casts your variable to an IDisposable interface, and if the cast suceeds it calls the Dispose method on it, inside the loop it calls the Current property and the MoveNext method repeatedly inside the loop, objects are being created underneath the covers. A lot of people use foreach because it's very easy coding, very easy to do.." .. "foreach is not very good in terms of performance, if you iterated over a collection instead by using square bracket notation, just doing index, that's just much faster, and it doesn't create any objects on the heap..."

On-Demand Webcast:
http://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?EventID=1032292286&EventCategory=3&culture=en-US&CountryCode=US

Answer (score 14):

you can read about it in [Deep .NET - part 1 Iteration](https://medium.com/deep-net/part-1-iteration-2f33bf5ea50f)

it's cover the results (without the first initialization) from .NET source code all the way to the disassembly.

for example - Array Iteration with a foreach loop:
[image]

and - list iteration with foreach loop:
[image]

and the end results:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In cases where you work with a collection of objects, `foreach` is better, but if you increment a number, a `for` loop is better.

Note that in the last case, you could do something like:

```
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))...
```

But it certainly doesn't perform better, it actually has worse performance compared to a `for`.

Comment: "Better" is debateable: It is slower and the dnspy debugger won't break into a C# foreach  (although VS2017 debugger will). Sometimes more readable but if you support languages without it, it can be annoying.

Answer (score 10):

This should save you:

```
public IEnumerator<int> For(int start, int end, int step) {
    int n = start;
    while (n <= end) {
        yield n;
        n += step;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
foreach (int n in For(1, 200, 4)) {
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

For greater win, you may take three delegates as parameters.

Comment: One tiny difference is that a `for` loop is usually written to exclude the end of the range (e.g. `0 <= i < 10`). `Parallel.For` also does that to keep it easily interchangeable with a common `for` loop.

Answer (score 9):

The differences in speed in a `for`- and a `foreach`-loop are tiny when you're looping through common structures like arrays, lists, etc, and doing a `LINQ` query over the collection is almost always slightly slower, although it's nicer to write! As the other posters said, go for expressiveness rather than a millisecond of extra performance.

What hasn't been said so far is that when a `foreach` loop is compiled, it is optimised by the compiler based on the collection it is iterating over. That means that when you're not sure which loop to use, you should use the `foreach` loop - it will generate the best loop for you when it gets compiled. It's more readable too.

Another key advantage with the `foreach` loop is that if your collection implementation changes (from an int `array` to a `List<int>` for example) then your `foreach` loop won't require any code changes:

```
foreach (int i in myCollection)
```

The above is the same no matter what type your collection is, whereas in your `for` loop, the following will not build if you changed `myCollection` from an `array` to a `List`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.Length, i++)
```

Answer (score 9):

This has the same two answers as most "which is faster" questions:

1) If you don't measure, you don't know.

2) (Because...) It depends.

It depends on how expensive the "MoveNext()" method is, relative to how expensive the "this[int index]" method is, for the type (or types) of IEnumerable that you will be iterating over.

The "foreach" keyword is shorthand for a series of operations - it calls GetEnumerator() once on the IEnumerable, it calls MoveNext() once per iteration, it does some type checking, and so on. The thing most likely to impact performance measurements is the cost of MoveNext() since that gets invoked O(N) times. Maybe it's cheap, but maybe it's not.

The "for" keyword looks more predictable, but inside most "for" loops you'll find something like "collection[index]". This looks like a simple array indexing operation, but it's actually a method call, whose cost depends entirely on the nature of the collection that you're iterating over. Probably it's cheap, but maybe it's not.

If the collection's underlying structure is essentially a linked list, MoveNext is dirt-cheap, but the indexer might have O(N) cost, making the true cost of a "for" loop O(N*N).

Answer (score 8):

"Are there any arguments I could use to help me convince him the for loop is acceptable to use?"

No, if your boss is micromanaging to the level of telling you what programming language constructs to use, there's really nothing you can say.  Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

It probably depends on the type of collection you are enumerating and the implementation of its indexer. In general though, using `foreach` is likely to be a better approach.

Also, it'll work with any `IEnumerable` - not just things with indexers.

Answer (score 7):

Every language construct has an appropriate time and place for usage.  There is a reason the C# language has a four separate [iteration statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664750(VS.71).aspx) - each is there for a specific purpose, and has an appropriate use.

I recommend sitting down with your boss and trying to rationally explain why a `for` loop has a purpose.  There are times when a `for` iteration block more clearly describes an algorithm than a `foreach` iteration.  When this is true, it is appropriate to use them.

I'd also point out to your boss - Performance is not, and should not be an issue in any practical way - it's more a matter of expression the algorithm in a succinct, meaningful, maintainable manner.  Micro-optimizations like this miss the point of performance optimization completely, since any real performance benefit will come from algorithmic redesign and refactoring, not loop restructuring.

If, after a rational discussion, there is still this authoritarian view, it is up to you as to how to proceed.  Personally, I would not be happy working in an environment where rational thought is discouraged, and would consider moving to another position under a different employer.  However, I strongly recommend discussion prior to getting upset - there may just be a simple misunderstanding in place.

Answer (score 6):

Whether `for` is faster than `foreach` is really besides the point. I seriously doubt that choosing one over the other will make a significant impact on your performance.

The best way to optimize your application is through profiling of the actual code. That will pinpoint the methods that account for the most work/time. Optimize those first. If performance is still not acceptable, repeat the procedure.

As a general rule I would recommend to stay away from micro optimizations as they will rarely yield any significant gains. Only exception is when optimizing identified hot paths (i.e. if your profiling identifies a few highly used methods, it may make sense to optimize these extensively).

Comment: If the only kind of optimization I needed to do in the projects I work on were micro optimizations, I would a happy camper. Sadly, this is never the case.

Comment: `for` is marginally faster than `foreach`. I'd seriously object to this statement. That totally depends on the underlying collection. If a linked list class provides an indexer with an integer parameter, I would expect using a `for` loop on it to be O(n^2) while `foreach` is expected to be O(n).

Comment: @Merhdad: Actually that is a good point. I was just thinking about the regular case of indexing a list (i.e. array). I'll reword to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: @Mehrdad Afshari: Indexing a collection by integer may be *much* slower than enumerating over it.  But you are actually comparing using `for` **and** an indexer lookup to using `foreach` by itself.  I think @Brian Rasmussen's answer is correct that, aside from any use with a collection, `for` will always be slightly faster than `foreach`.  However, `for` plus a collection lookup will always be slower than `foreach` by itself.

Comment: @Daniel: Either you have a plain array, for which both will generate identical code, or there's an indexer involved when you use `for` statement. Plain `for` loop with an integer control variable is not comparable to `foreach`, so that's out. I understand what @Brian means and it's correct as you say but the answer can be misleading. Re: your last point: no, actually, `for` over `List<T>` is still faster than `foreach`.

Comment: @Mehrdad- Surely with a LinkedList you'd write something like for(var node= list.Head; node != null; node = node.Next) if you wanted to use a for loop, making it O(n).

Comment: @RichardOD: The linked list class I was imagining abstracts away the nodes from you and you can either access items with a number, or with `foreach` ;) Anyway, my point is, strictly speaking, without knowing the underlying collection and the way it works, you can't say one is faster than another. It's like saying method `A()` is faster than `B()` without having an idea what they are doing.

Answer (score 5):

It is what you do *inside* the loop that affects perfomance, not the actual looping construct (assuming your case is non-trivial).

Answer (score 4):

The two will run almost exactly the same way.  Write some code to use both, then show him the IL.  It should show comparable computations, meaning no difference in performance.

Comment: The compiler recognises foreach loops used on arrays/ILists etc and changes them to for loops.

Comment: Show him lines of unintelligble *proof* that it is OK and ask for his proof that it is not OK.

Answer (score 4):

It seems a bit strange to totally forbid the use of something like a for loop.

There's an interesting article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/foreach.aspx) that covers a lot of the performance differences between the two loops.

I would say personally I find foreach a bit more readable over for loops but you should use the best for the job at hand and not have to write extra long code to include a foreach loop if a for loop is more appropriate.

Comment: Essential quote form the article you link to: "...if you are planning to write high performance code that is not for collections, use for loop. Even for collections, foreach may look handy when using, but it's not that efficient. "

Answer (score 4):

In most cases there's really no difference.

Typically you always have to use foreach when you don't have an explicit numerical index, and you always have to use for when you don't actually have an iterable collection (e.g. iterating over a two-dimensional array grid in an upper triangle).  There are some cases where you have a choice.

One could argue that for loops can be a little more difficult to maintain if magic numbers start to appear in the code.  You should be right to be annoyed at not being able to use a for loop and have to build a collection or use a lambda to build a subcollection instead just because for loops have been banned.

Answer (score 4):

You can really screw with his head and go for an IQueryable .foreach closure instead:

```
myList.ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
```

Comment: I'd replace your line of code with `myList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine)`.

Comment: LINQ `ForEach` use `for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)` but for every iteration it also checks that the collection has not changed.

Answer (score 4):

A powerful and precise way to measure time is by using the [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) library.

In the following sample, I did a loop on 1,000,000,000 integer records on `for`/`foreach` and measured it with [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet):

```cs
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<LoopsBenchmarks>();
    }
}

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class LoopsBenchmarks
{
    private List<int> arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 1_000_000_000).ToList();

    [Benchmark]
    public void For()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
        {
            int item = arr[i];
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Foreach()
    {
        foreach (int item in arr)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the results:

[image]

### Conclusion

In the example above we can see that `for` loop is slightly faster than `foreach` loop for lists. We can also see that both use the same memory allocation.

Comment: I think you need `int item = arr[i];` in the body of the `for` to make it a fair comparison, and it'd be good to do _some_ work (e.g. `sum += item;`) in the body of both loops. Since BenchmarkDotNet makes it easy to do so, it'd be interesting to compare runs between .NET Framework and Core. Another benchmark to add might be to see if caching the collection size in a variable for the loop condition (i.e. `int length = arr.Length; for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { }`) yields appreciable improvement; perhaps that's more significant for non-`Array` implementations of `IList<>`.

Comment: This matches a benchmark I did.  Thanks for giving an updated answer, because the 14 year old accepted answer is no longer correct in my opinion.  I hope we can push this answer up the ranks!

Answer (score 3):

I did test it a while ago, with the result that a `for` loop is much faster than a `foreach` loop. The cause is simple, the `foreach` loop first needs to instantiate an `IEnumerator` for the collection.

Comment: Not with an array it doesn't. Compile it and look at the IL :) (It also depends on the collection. IIRC, List<T> uses a value type for the enumerator.)

Comment: Why would one allocation be expensive? In managed .NET, allocations are practically free aren't they, since all that is done is that the pointer is incremented in the managed heap, there is little if any fragmentation in most cases.

Comment: not just one allocation, also all the method-calling overhead of MoveNext() and get_Current() for each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

for has more simple logic to implement so it's faster than foreach.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're in a specific speed optimization process, I would say use whichever method produces the easiest to read and maintain code.

If an iterator is already setup, like with one of the collection classes, then the foreach is a good easy option.  And if it's an integer range you're iterating, then for is probably cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Jeffrey Richter talked the performance difference between for and foreach on  a recent podcast: http://pixel8.infragistics.com/shows/everything.aspx#Episode:9317

Answer (score 3):

I found the `foreach` loop which iterating through a `List` **faster**. See my test results below. In the code below I iterate an `array` of size 100, 10000 and 100000 separately using `for` and `foreach` loop to measure the time.

[image]

```
private static void MeasureTime()
    {
        var array = new int[10000];
        var list = array.ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("Array size: {0}", array.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("Array For loop ......");
        var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time take to run the for loop is {0} millisecond", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("Array Foreach loop ......");
        var stopWatch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        stopWatch1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time take to run the foreach loop is {0} millisecond", stopWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("List For loop ......");
        var stopWatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        stopWatch2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time take to run the for loop is {0} millisecond", stopWatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("List Foreach loop ......");
        var stopWatch3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        stopWatch3.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time take to run the foreach loop is {0} millisecond", stopWatch3.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

## UPDATED

After @jgauffin suggestion I used @johnskeet code and found that the `for` loop with `array` is faster than following,

- Foreach loop with array.
- For loop with list.
- Foreach loop with list.

See my test results and code below,

[image]

```
private static void MeasureNewTime()
    {
        var data = new double[Size];
        var rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = rng.NextDouble();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Lenght of array: {0}", data.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("No. of iteration: {0}", Iterations);
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        double correctSum = data.Sum();

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
            {
                sum += data[j];
            }
            if (Math.Abs(sum - correctSum) > 0.1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Summation failed");
                return;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("For loop with Array: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            foreach (double d in data)
            {
                sum += d;
            }
            if (Math.Abs(sum - correctSum) > 0.1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Summation failed");
                return;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Foreach loop with Array: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        var dataList = data.ToList();
        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < dataList.Count; j++)
            {
                sum += data[j];
            }
            if (Math.Abs(sum - correctSum) > 0.1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Summation failed");
                return;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("For loop with List: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            foreach (double d in dataList)
            {
                sum += d;
            }
            if (Math.Abs(sum - correctSum) > 0.1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Summation failed");
                return;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Foreach loop with List: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Comment: This is a very poor test. a) you do too few iterations to get a conclusive answer b) That Thread.Sleep will not really wait one millisecond. Use the same method as Jon Skeet did in his answer.

Comment: 99.99% of the time is definately spent in the thread.sleep (which makes no guarantees of how fast it will return except it won't before at least that time). Looping is very fast and sleeping is very slow, you don't use the later to test the former.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect anyone to find a "huge" performance difference between the two.

I guess the answer depends on the whether the collection you are trying to access has a faster indexer access implementation or a faster IEnumerator access implementation. Since IEnumerator often uses the indexer and just holds a copy of the current index position, I would expect enumerator access to be at least as slow or slower than direct index access, but not by much.

Of course this answer doesn't account for any optimizations the compiler may implement.

Comment: The C# compiler does very little optimisation, it really leaves that up to the JITter.

Comment: Well, the JITter is a compiler... Right?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the for-loop and foreach-loop are not always equivalent. List enumerators will throw an exception if the list changes, but you won't always get that warning with a normal for loop. You might even get a different exception if the list changes at just the wrong time.

Comment: If the list is changing out from under you then you cannot rely on the enumerator backing a foreach loop to tell you that.  It is not going to check again after it returns the value to you, resulting in a race.

Answer (score 1):

I think for is marginally faster than foreach in most cases, but this is really missing the point. One thing I haven't seen mentioned is that, in the scenario you're talking about (i.e., a high volume web app), the difference in performance between for and foreach is going to have no bearing on the site's performance. You're going to be limited by request/response time and DB time, not for v. foreach.

That said, I don't understand your aversion to foreach. In my opinion, foreach is usually clearer in situation where either could be used. I usually reserve for for situations where I need to traverse a collection in some ugly, non-standard way.

Comment: I like to be able to control things by index.  In a foreach loop, you have to instead setup a variable and increment it inside the foreach if you need a counter.  I guess if you don't need the index then I am fine with a foreach.

Comment: That's valid. I just find in most scenarios I want to "do something" to each element. If you need to know where you are in the collection, for is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In my project in Windows Mobile I used a `for` loop for a control collection. It took 100 ms for 20 controls! A `foreach` loop used only 4 ms. That was a performance problem...

Answer (score 1):

Ben Watson, the author of "Writing High-Performance .NET Code":

> "Will these optimization matter to your program? Only if your program
>   is CPU bound and collection iteration is a core part of your
>   processing. As you'll see, there are ways you can hurt your
>   performance if you're not careful, but that only matters if it was a
>   significant part of your program to begin with. My philosophy is this:
>   most people never need to know this, but if you do, then understanding
>   every layer of the system is important so that you can make
>   intelligent choices".

The most exaustive explanation can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/844781/Digging-Into-NET-Loop-Performance-Bounds-checking

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a case where foreach way WAY faster than For

[why foreach is faster than for loop while reading richtextbox lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136825/why-foreach-is-faster-than-for-loop-while-reading-richtextbox-lines/1136863#comment66437239_1136863)

I had a case similar to the OP in that question.

A textbox reading about 72K lines, and I was accessling the Lines property(which is actually a getter method).  (And apparently often in winforms there are getter methods that aren't O(1). I suppose it's O(n), so the larger the textbox the longer it takes to get a value from that 'property'. And in the for loop I had as the OP there had `for(int i=0;i<textBox1.lines.length;i++) str=textBox1.Lines[i]`  , and it was really quite slow as it was reading the entire textbox each time it read a line plus it was reading the entire textbox each time it checked the condition.

Jon Skeet shows that you can do it accessing the Lines property just one single time(not even once per iteration, just once). Rather than twice on each iteration (which is a ton of times). Do string[] strarrlines = textBox1.Lines; and loop through the strarrlines.

But certainly a for loop in a fairly intuitive form and accessing the Lines property, is very inefficient

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    s = richTextBox.Lines[i];
}
```

for a textbox, or a rich textbox, it's super slow.

The OP, testing that loop on a rich textbox, found that " with 15000 lines.for loop took 8 minutes to just loop down to 15000 lines.while foreach took fraction of a second to enumerate it."

The OP at that link found this foreach to be far more efficient than his(The same OP's) for loop mentioned above. As I did.

```
   String s=String.Empty;
   foreach(string str in txtText.Lines)
    {
       s=str;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't so much the fault of `for` but rather that `Lines` works like a method (building a new result on each access) but is misleadingly defined as a property.  You'd see the same issue with `IEnumerable<int> lines = Enumerable.Range(0, 1_000_000).Select(i => i.ToString()); for (int i = 0; i < lines.ToArray().Length; i++) s = lines.ToArray()[i];` except there it's obvious that access pattern is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
    internal static void Test()
    {
        int LOOP_LENGTH = 10000000;
        Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());

        {
            Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            long first_memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            {
                dict.Add(i, i);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_LENGTH; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < dict.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (dict[k] > 1000000) Console.WriteLine("Test");
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            var last_memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary for T:{stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s\t M:{last_memory - first_memory}");

            GC.Collect();
        }


        {
            Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            long first_memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            {
                dict.Add(i, i);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_LENGTH; i++)
            {
                foreach (var item in dict)
                {
                    if (item.Value > 1000000) Console.WriteLine("Test");
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            var last_memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary foreach T:{stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s\t M:{last_memory - first_memory}");

            GC.Collect();
        }

        {
            Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            long first_memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            {
                dict.Add(i, i);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_LENGTH; i++)
            {
                foreach (var item in dict.Values)
                {
                    if (item > 1000000) Console.WriteLine("Test");
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            var last_memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary foreach values T:{stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s\t M:{last_memory - first_memory}");

            GC.Collect();
        }


        {
            List<int> dict = new List<int>();
            long first_memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            {
                dict.Add(i);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_LENGTH; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < dict.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (dict[k] > 1000000) Console.WriteLine("Test");
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            var last_memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            Console.WriteLine($"list for T:{stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s\t M:{last_memory - first_memory}");

            GC.Collect();
        }


        {
            List<int> dict = new List<int>();
            long first_memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            {
                dict.Add(i);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_LENGTH; i++)
            {
                foreach (var item in dict)
                {
                    if (item > 1000000) Console.WriteLine("Test");
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            var last_memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            Console.WriteLine($"list foreach T:{stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s\t M:{last_memory - first_memory}");

            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Dictionary for T:10.1957728s     M:2080
Dictionary foreach T:10.5900586s         M:1952
Dictionary foreach values T:3.8294776s   M:2088
list for T:3.7981471s    M:320
list foreach T:4.4861377s        M:648

Answer (score 1):

I think it'll be much faster with the `Parallel.ForEach()` along with `ConcurrentDictionary` or `ConcurrentBag`

Here example of `Parallel.ForEach()`

```
var primeNumbers = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
Parallel.ForEach(numbers, number =>
{
    if (IsPrime(number))
    {
        primeNumbers.Add(number);
    }
});
```

And

```
var productImage = new ConcurrentDictionary<int,ResultModel>();
Parallel.ForEach(pendingActiveImagesBatch, pictureItem =>
{                           
    productImage.TryAdd(pictureItem.Id,pictureItem));
});
```

- [Reference Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)
- [Reference ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Note that this is not a complete substitute to the `for` and `foreach` cause it will not preserve order of elements. Also you need `ForEachAsync` to handle async calls.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/foreach.aspx) for a specific answer. The conclusion of the article is that using for loop is generally better and faster than the foreach loop.

Comment: That conclusion was written in 2004. Things have moved on. See my benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

At least I haven't seen any of my collegues or higher ups saying that, that's just ridiculous considering the fact that there is no significant speed difference between `for` and `foreach`. The same applies if he is asking to use it in all cases!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do parsing of some large data using three nested loops (on `List<MyCustomType>`). I thought, using Rob Fonseca-Ensor's post above, it'd be interesting to time and compare the difference using **for** and **foreach**.

The difference was:
The foreach (three foreach nested like foreach{foreach{forech{}}} did the job in **171.441** seconds where as for (for{for{for{}}}) did it in **158.616** seconds.

Now 13 seconds is about **13%** reduction in time to do this - which is somewhat significant to me. However, foreach is definitely far more readable than using three indexed-fors...

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned this details based on speed of collection on for and foreach.

List -For Loop is slightly faster than Foreach Loop

ArrayList -  For Loop is about more than 2 times faster speed than Foreach Loop.

Array - Both are in equal speed.But Foreach Loop seems to be a bit faster.

Comment: What is the basis of these conclusions?