# DataTable.Select vs DataTable.rows.Find vs foreach vs Find(Predicate<T>)/Lambda

Tags: .net, optimization, lambda, anonymous-methods

I have a DataTable/collection that is cached in memory, I want to use this as a source to generate results for an auto complete textbox (using AJAX of course).
I am evaluating various options to fetch the data quickly. 
The number of items in the collection/rows in the datatable could vary from 10000 to 2,000,000. (So that we dont get diverted, for the moment assume that the decision has been made, I have ample RAM and I will be using the cache and not database query for this)

I have some additional business logic for this processing; I have to prioritize the auto complete list as per a `priority` column (int) in the collection. So if I someone searches for `Micro` and I get say 20 results of words/sentences that start with `Micro` then I would pick the top 10 resultant items with highest priority. (hence the need to have a priority property associated with the string value).

The collection items are already sorted alphabetically.

What would be the best solution in this case.
1. Using DataTable.Select(.
2. [Using DataTable.Rows.Find(](http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/648398-datatable-select-vs-datatable-rows-find-vs-foreach).
 
3. use a custom collection with [foreach or for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615) to iterate through its values.
4. use a generic collection with [anonymous delegates](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2007/03/26/find-items-inside-a-generic-list-using-the-old-approach-the-cool-approach-and-the-super-duper-cool-approach.aspx) or lambda ([since both give same performance](http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=306) or [not](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx)?)

Answer (score 8):

The charts aren't posted on my blog entry; more details can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364983.aspx

One other thing that I've since discovered is that, for large data sets, using a chained generic dictionary performs incredibly well. It also helps alleviate many of the issues caused by the sort operations required for aggregation operations such as min and max (either with `DataTable.Compute` or `LINQ`).

By "chained generic dictionary," I mean a `Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of DataRow))))` or similar technique, where the key for each dictionary is a search term.

Granted, this won't be useful in all circumstances, but I have at least one scenario where implementing this approach lead to a `500x` performance improvement.

In your case, I'd consider using a simple dictionary with the first 1-5 characters, then a `List(Of String)`. You'd have to build up this dictionary once, adding the words to the lists with the first 1-5 characters, but after that you'll be able to get blazingly fast results.

I generally wrap things like this in a class that allows me to do things like add words easily. You may also want to use a `SortedList(Of String)`, to get the results sorted automatically. This way, you can quickly look up the list of words that match the first N characters that have been typed.

Comment: And you are quite `Certain` about that!

Comment: Hi! @jeffcertain 

I wanted to download the code of your article [Scaling ADO(dot)NET DataTables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364983.aspx)
The code was however not found at both Microsoft's website or at GitHub Archive/Archive.org

I kindly request you to send a copy to forumresearcher007atgmail.com
Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

On my `autocomplete`, i tried first the `linq/lambda` approach, the performance is a little slow. `DataTable.Select` is faster than `linq`, so I use this. I haven't yet compared the performance between `datatable.Select` and `datatable.Find`

Comment: Did you have index on filtering key?

Comment: The poster's question is about filtering the DataTable. So the database index can't be applied here. DataTable has internal in-memory index for rows, and it is accessible only through DataTable.Select(I suppose DataTable.Find can also access that internal index). Linq-to-object can't access that internal index, as under-the-hood Linq-to-object loops all the elements. Unless someone will make a Linq-to-DataTable provider that uses DataTable.Select internally, filtering DataRow from DataTable using Linq/Lambda will still be disappointing. DataTable architecture http://j.mp/k56g37

Comment: My question was about DataTable internal index. Also according to  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364983.aspx "indexing the table provides a minor advantage to the LINQ query"

Comment: If you think about it, index and Linq are an overloaded word ;-)

Answer (score 2):

We could speculate about it all day, but since this is not a huge piece of code, why not write each one and benchmark them against each other?

```
public delegate void TestProcedure();

public TimeSpan Benchmark(TestProcedure tp)
{
    int testBatchSize = 5;
    List<TimeSpan> results = new List<TimeSpan>();
    for(int i = 0; i<testBatchSize; i++)
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        tp();
        results.Add(DateTime.Now - start);
    }
    return results.Min();
}
```

Comment: Well just checking if anyone has already `been there done that`!

Comment: If you do benchmark it, let us know!  I'm curious what you will find.

Answer (score 1):

as per the following blog

http://blog.dotnetspeech.net/archive/2008/08/26/performance----datatable.select-vs-dictionary.aspx

DataTable.Rows.Find is much, much faster than DataTable.Select.

Comment: The blog's author is Jeff Certain who has detailed answer above and an article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364983.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

What about a DataView? You could apply your filter condition AND sort by the the priority, and easily iterate through the results to add to your results.

Comment: Yes option 2 in the question does exactly this.