# Are lambda functions faster than delegates/anonymous functions?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-function, lambda

I assumed `lambda functions`, `delegates` and `anonymous functions` with the same body would have the same "speed", however, running the following simple program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> items = new List<int>();

    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        items.Add(random.Next());
    }

    Stopwatch watch;
    IEnumerable<int> result;

    Func<int, bool> @delegate = delegate(int i)
    {
        return i < 500;
    };
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    result = items.Where(@delegate);
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Delegate: {0}", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

    Func<int, bool> lambda = i => i < 500;
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    result = items.Where(lambda);
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Lambda: {0}", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    result = items.Where(i => i < 500);
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Inline: {0}", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I get:

> Delegate: 4.2948 ms
>
> Lambda: 0.0019 ms
>
> Anonymous: 0.0034 ms

Although negligible, why are these three - apparently identical - methods running at different speeds? What's happening under the hood?

---

**Update:**

As suggested by the comments, the following "forces" the `Where` by calling `ToList()` on it. In addition, a loop is added to offer more run data:

```
while (true) 
{
    List<int> items = new List<int>();

    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        items.Add(random.Next());
    }

    Stopwatch watch;
    IEnumerable<int> result;

    Func<int, bool> @delegate = delegate(int i)
    {
        return i < 500;
    };
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    result = items.Where(@delegate).ToList();
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Delegate: {0}", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

    Func<int, bool> lambda = i => i < 500;
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    result = items.Where(lambda).ToList();
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Lambda: {0}", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    result = items.Where(i => i < 500).ToList();
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Inline: {0}", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 12));

}
```

The above code results in ~120 ms for each function.

Comment: just out of curiosity, did you try running the 3 in different orders?

Comment: The second and third are both lambdas.

Comment: Add warmup period and run all tests several cycles (big loop around all) and force Where. After these changes I see no perceptible difference.

Comment: The first one will take ages, no matter what order you run them. Clearly a bunch of stuff is happening under the hood right before the first test. Once you account for that they're all the same.

Comment: @pst - wow, silly me, I completely forgot about forcing `Where`. With an outer loop, warm up time, forced `Where`, all methods were averaging 120-125 ms.

Comment: What's the effect of the `@` in this code? (@delegate)

Comment: Charles>> delegate is a reserved keyword but he get around that by naming it @delegate.

Comment: @Omar: The code you've *shown* certainly wouldn't take 120ms - I suggest you edit the code to show how you're "forcing" Where.

Comment: @Mikael: thanks - didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A lambda expression *is* an anonymous function. "Anonymous function" refers to either a lambda expression or an anonymous method (which is what *you've* called a "delegate" in your code).

All three operations are using delegates. The second and third are both using lambda expressions. All three will execute in the same way, with the same performance characteristics.

Note that there *can* be a difference in performance between:

```
Func<int, int> func = x => ...;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    CallFunc(func);
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    CallFunc(x => ...) // Same lambda as before
}
```

It depends on whether the compiler is able to cache the delegate created by the lambda expression. That will in turn depend on whether it captures variables etc.

For example, consider this code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Test
{
    const int Iterations = 1000000000;

    static void Main()
    {
        AllocateOnce();
        AllocateInLoop();
    }

    static void AllocateOnce()
    {
        int x = 10;

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int sum = 0;
        Func<int, int> allocateOnce = y => y + x;
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            sum += Apply(i, allocateOnce);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Allocated once: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    static void AllocateInLoop()
    {
        int x = 10;

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            sum += Apply(i, y => y + x);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Allocated in loop: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    static int Apply(int loopCounter, Func<int, int> func)
    {
        return func(loopCounter);
    }
}
```

The compiler is smart, but there's still a difference. Using Reflector, we can see that `AllocateInLoop` is effectively compiled to:

```
private static void AllocateInLoop()
{
    Func<int, int> func = null;
    int x = 10;
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
    {
        if (func == null)
        {
            func = y => y + x;
        }
        sum += Apply(i, func);
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Allocated in loop: {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

So still only a single delegate instance is created, but there's extra logic within the loop - an extra nullity test on each iteration, basically.

On my machine that makes about a 15% difference in performance.

Comment: I am not sure how you go about examining the IL output, but I assume that `delegate { Foo(); }` and `() => { Foo(); }` would compile to the same IL right?

Comment: @LeaHayes: I'd expect so, yes.

Answer (score 22):

Other peoples results suggest that the performance is the same:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2007/12/11/anonymous-delegates-vs-lambda-expressions-vs-function-calls-performance.aspx

As noted in the comments, micro-benchmarks are often misleading. There are too many factors over which you have no control, JIT optimisation, garbage collection cycles, etc ...

See this related question:

[When not to use lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672918/when-not-to-use-lambda-expressions)

**Finally, I think your test is fundamentally flawed!** You use a Linq `Where` extension method to execute your code. However, Linq uses lazy-evaluation, your code will only be executed if you start iterating over the results!

Comment: Can you make the last paragraph bold? :)