# Pass generic type parameter to Func

Tags: c#, generics, func

I have a couple of function like `CallMyFunction` in my codebase. I would like to refactor them into one generic function

```
enum MyEnum
{
    ValueA,
    ValueB,
    ValueC
}

static void MyFunction<T>()
{
    //...
}

static void CallMyFunction(MyEnum myEnum)
{
    switch (myEnum)
    {
        case MyEnum.ValueA:
            MyFunction<A>();
            break;
        case MyEnum.ValueB:
            MyFunction<B>();
            break;
        case MyEnum.ValueC:
            MyFunction<C>();
            break;                                                              
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to have something like

```
//I would like to make it work for Func<T> too
static void GenericCall(MyEnum myEnum, Action<?????> myFunc) 
{
    switch (myEnum)
    {
        case MyEnum.ValueA:
            myFunc<A>();
            break;
        case MyEnum.ValueB:
            myFunc<B>();
            break;
        case MyEnum.ValueC:
            myFunc<C>();
            break;                                                              
    }
}

//And then call it like this
GenericCall(myEnum, MyFunction);
GenericCall(myEnum, AnotherFunction);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply create a dictionary of *myenum/action* pairs

Your  dictionary:

```
Dictionary<MyEnum,Action> actions = new Dictionary<MyEnum,Action>()
{
    {ValueA, ()=>{your code...}},
    {ValueB, ()=>{your code...}}
};
```

calling a method

```
static void CallMyFunction(MyEnum myEnum)
{
    actions[myEnum]();
}
```

Comment: According to the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617091/in-a-switch-vs-dictionary-for-a-value-of-func-which-is-faster-and-why, this may impact performance.

Comment: @KOTIX I agree if you have a millions of cases for a switch.

Comment: @KOTIX, you'd also have the performance overhead of the lambda. It's a fairly clean approach though if you're ok with the performance overhead.

Comment: @DiskJunky What is overhead of lamba other than calling a function in this case?

Comment: @L.B the answer to that would take longer than I could reasonably put into a comment :) TL;DR version is that .NET has to do some wrangling to work out how to call the lambda and the JIT isn't a fan if performance is critical. Explicit methods are easier for it to deal with

Comment: @L.B, it's a big topic; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672918/when-not-to-use-lambda-expressions.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. What I want to do is to only do one switch-case and then calling it by only passing my function. I edited the question to add examples of how I want to use it

Comment: @DiskJunky A lamda query is just function call determined at compile time. Not a big topic. `x=>x==1` is just equals to `delegate(int i){ return x==1;}`

Comment: @L.B that doesn't quite sit with my (limited) understanding of how the JIT deals with lambdas but I'll bow to your greater expertise on this. Consider it moot.

Comment: @Bruno I think Eser's answer does exactly what you want to do and is better approach than yours

Comment: @L.B not really, he's just converting a switch case to a dictionary. Which is basically less safe (no possible warning if I want to add a new value in your Enum). Also, you have to do a new dictionary every time you want to use the enum with another function, which is the same code duplication that I already have.

Comment: @Bruno you have to pick the method to call *somehow*. Be it via `Dictionary` or `switch` or even `if` is moot. Your alternative is to call the appropriate method instead of where you're calling `MyFunction` as it is at present. If you don't want your decider to be the *caller* of `MyFunction` then the selection must be put inside it, regardless if which mechanism you choose.

Comment: @Bruno Question is yours, use this post or not, but all of your arguments in previous comment are invalid (about safity, code duplicates etc. I think you didn't understand this answer enough)

Comment: I don't understand why my arguments are invalid, I just want to be able to remove some duplicated code and your answer doesn't solve the issue, since I would have to do one dictionary per function instead of a switch-case per function, which is basically the same thing

Comment: @Bruno it *is* pretty much the same thing but what it does is allow for shorter code as you're writing one line for each call to `Add` rather than spelling out each `case` and `break` in a `switch`. How you select doesn't much matter as you have to select somehow, regardless of what approach is taken. This reduces the question to "what's the shortest way to select my function?"

Comment: @DiskJunky I'm not trying to golf my function, I'm trying to avoid duplicate like I said 3 times

Comment: @Bruno we're going by the example you've posted. `myFunc<A>`, `myFunc<B>` and `myFunc<C>` are not the same things - no duplication. These are selected by `enum` meaning that *something* has to tie the `enum` to the `<>`. This can be a `swtich`, `Dictionary`, `Attribute`etc. but something has to spell it out. It can't be decided by the caller of `CallMyFunction` (and hence a generic), or there's no point at all in `CallMyFunction`. You're just putting the decision on the caller rather than in `CallMyFunction` itself. If you have a more explicit example, we can try to work with that

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there are no *parameters* for any calls to `MyFunction<>`, meaning there are no generic arguments required for `Action`. Likewise, you cannot change to `CallMyFunction<T>` as `T` changes depending on the `enum`.

As for `<A>`, `<B>` and `<C>`, these have to be specified in each `case` rather than put in as part of a generic argument to `Action`. The `switch` is calling the methods, not the caller of `GenericCall`. It's this key point that you're working around, to dynamically select `<A>`, `<B>` and `<C>` based on the `enum` value.

Trying to put an argument into `CallMyFunction` for `myFunc` effectively means the caller has to supply the types `A`, `B` and `C` which negates the purpose of the `switch`. This isn't what you're trying to do I think.

One way of refactoring would be to change the method `MyFunction<T>` to take the type parameter as a parameter rather than a generic. This would allow you to do the following;

```
enum MyEnum
{
    ValueA,
    ValueB,
    ValueC
}

static void MyFunction(Type type)
{
    //...
}

static void CallMyFunction(MyEnum myEnum)
{
    Type type;
    switch (myEnum)
    {
        case MyEnum.ValueA:
            type = typeof(A);
            break;
        case MyEnum.ValueB:
            type = typeof(B);
            break;
        case MyEnum.ValueC:
            type = typeof(C);
            break;                                                              
    }
    MyFunction(type);
}
```

However this doesn't really save you anything.

To get proper value out of it, you could create a custom `Attribute` that took a constructor argument of `Type` and apply the `Attribute` directly to the `enum`. Your function `MyFunction`, could be modified to check for the `Attribute` on the enum and correctly pass the correct type to `MyFunction`.

That said, it'd only be worth it if you had a large (>10) `enum` values/types. The structure as it stands is fairly straight forward and easy (if mundane), to maintain.

It's worth mentioning that you could also use reflection to call `MyFunction<>` and supply the generic argument at runtime but you'd still be left with picking out the type by `enum`. It would add more code to maintain rather than reduce it.