# Is there any method like ForEach for IList?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

`List<T>` has a method called `ForEach` which executes the passed action on each element of it.

```
var names = new List<String>{ "Bruce", "Alfred", "Tim", "Richard" };

names.ForEach(p =>  { Console.WriteLine(p); });
```

But what if `names` is not a `List<T>` but an `IList<T>`? `IList<T>` doesn't have a method like `ForEach`.

Is there some alternative?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var p in names) {
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

There is no reason to use delegates and extension methods all over the place if that doesn't actually improve readability; a `foreach` loop is not any less explicitly telling readers what's being done than a `ForEach` method.

Answer (score 26):

If your `IList<T>` is an array (`T[]`), then you have [Array.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) method on them similar to `ForEach` on `List<T>`. You can create an extension method for your custom `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` or whatever you prefer.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IList<T> list, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T t in list)
        action(t);
}
```

You just have to be wary of the fact that the objects in the original collection will be modified, but I guess the naming does imply that.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I prefer to call:

```
people.Where(p => p.Tenure > 5)
      .Select(p => p.Nationality)
      .ForEach(n => AssignCitizenShip(n);
```

than

```
foreach (var n in people.Where(p => p.Tenure > 5).Select(p => p.Nationality))
{
    AssignCitizenShip(n);
}
```

If so you can create the extension method on `IEnumerable`. Mind you the terminating call `ForEach` executes the `Linq` query. If you do not want it, you can defer it too by using `yield` statement and returning an `IEnumerable<T>` back:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T t in list)
    {
        action(t);
        yield return t;
    }
}
```

That solves the side-effect issue, but I personally like a method named `ForEach` to finally execute the call.

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

To address the opposing views on preferences, [here is a better link](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) from Eric Lippert than [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mazhou/archive/2011/09/21/why-no-foreach-method-on-ienumerable-interfaces.aspx). To quote him:

> "The first reason is that doing so violates the functional programming
> principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon.
> Clearly the sole purpose of a call to this method is to cause side
> effects. The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to
> cause a side effect. The purpose of a statement is to cause a side
> effect. The call site of this thing would look an awful lot like an
> expression (though, admittedly, since the method is void-returning,
> the expression could only be used in a “statement expression”
> context.) It does not sit well with me to make the one and only
> sequence operator that is only useful for its side effects.
>
> The second reason is that doing so adds zero new representational
> power to the language".

Eric's not saying it's a bad thing to do - just the **philosophical** reasons behind the decision to not include  the construct in `Linq` by default. If you believe a function on an `IEnumerable` shouldn't act on the contents, then don't do it. Personally I dont mind it since I'm well aware what it does. I treat it as any other method that causes side-effect on a collection class. I can enter into the function and debug it too if I want. Here is another one from `Linq` itself.

```
people.Where(p => p.Tenure > 5)
      .Select(p => p.Nationality)
      .AsParallel()
      .ForAll(n => AssignCitizenShip(n);
```

As I would say, there is nothing bad about these. Its just personal preference. **I wouldn't use this for nested `foreach`s or if it involves more than one line of code to execute inside the `foreach` loop since thats plain unreadable.** But for simple example I posted, I like it. Looks clean and concise.

**Edit:** See a performance link btw: [Why is List<T>.ForEach faster than standard foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744085/why-is-listt-foreach-faster-than-standard-foreach?lq=1)

Answer (score 8):

You could make an extension method and use most of the implementation of `void List<T>.ForEach(Action<T> action)`. You can download the source code at the [Shared Source Initiative](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) site.

Basically you will end to something like this:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IList<T> list, Action<T> action) 
{
    if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("null");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        action(list[i]);
    }
}
```

It is slightly better than the other implementations that use the `foreach` statement since it takes advantage of the fact that IList includes an indexer.

Although I aggree with the answer of O. R. Mapper, sometimes in big projects with many developers it is hard to convicne everybody that a `foreach` statement is clearer. Even worse, if your API is based on interfaces (IList) instead of concrete types (List) then developers that are used to the `List<T>.ForEach method` might start calling `ToList` on your IList references! I know because it happened in my previous project. I was using the collection interfaces everywhere in our public APIs following the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613). It took me a while to notice that many developers where not used to this and call to `ToList` started apprearing with an alarming rate. Finally I added this extension method to a common assembly that everybody was using and made sure that all unecessary call to `ToList` were removed from the codebase.

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to static class and call it extensions:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IList<T> list, Action<T> action) {
    foreach(var item in list) {
        action.Invoke(item);
    }
}
```