# why foreach is faster than for loop while reading richtextbox lines

Tags: richtextbox

There are two ways to read data from RichTextBox line by line

1 ) use a for loop to loop through lines of a richtextBox

```
String s=String.Empty;
for(int i=0;i<richtextbox.lines.length;i++)
 {
     s=richTextBox.Lines[i]
 }
```

2 ) use a foreach loop to enumerate richTextBox.Lines collection

```
   String s=String.Empty;
   foreach(string str in txtText.Lines)
    {
       s=str;
    }
```

There is a huge difference in performance when we use foreach loop to enumerate array collection for richtextbox.

I tried with 15000 lines.for loop took 8 minutes to just loop down to 15000 lines.while foreach took fraction of a second to enumerate it.

Why is this behaviour there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Mehrdad noted, accessing the `Lines` property takes a long time. You need to be careful here - you're accessing it *twice* in each iteration at the moment:

```
String s = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    s = richTextBox.Lines[i];
}
```

Even if you remove the access in the body of the loop like this:

```
String s = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox.Lines.Length; i++)
{
}
```

you're *still* accessing `Lines` on every iteration to see if you've finished!

If you don't want to `foreach`, you can just fetch `Lines` once:

```
string[] lines = richTextBox.Lines;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    s = lines[i];
}
```

Personally I prefer the `foreach` unless you really need the index though :)

Comment: if it's the accessing twice that is the issue then shouldn't it just take twice as long. But his difference is 8 min vs a fraction of a second.

Comment: @barlop: No, it's not the difference between once or twice, it's the difference between once and once-per-line.

Answer (score 10):

I think the `Lines` property is recalculated every time you want to access it. Consequently, the `foreach` method performs the calculation only once, while every time your reference `Lines[i]` it's re-evaluating the whole thing. Try caching the result of `Lines` property and checking again:

```
String s = String.Empty;
var lines = richtextbox.Lines;
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    s = lines[i];
}
```

By the way, your question makes an implicit assumption that `foreach` is always slower than `for`. This is not always true.

Comment: but then why is it so fast using foreach.

Comment: foreach will translate to a single call to `Lines` property. It calls `GetEnumerator()` on it and only uses the resulting enumerator. The `Lines` property is never called again.

Comment: +1 The Lines property, inherited from TextBoxBase, reads the Text property and loops through it, character by character, to split them into rows. Calling that 30k times (15k loops, twice to check length and read value) will be slower than calling it once.

Comment: WinForms is full of non-O(1) properties. These kind of things should really be methods IMO. Making them properties can cause headaches in hunting down performance bugs.

Comment: IS there any way to choose between for and foreach loop.

Comment: Rohit: `foreach` is usually preferred unless you need to access things by index. If what you are trying to do is "for every item in the collection, do this thing" in your mind, you should normally go with `foreach`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because finding the next line in the textbox takes time. When you use random-access by indexing in the first case, it must find that line from scratch. When the iteration is done internally by `foreach`, it can retain state and quickly find the next line.

This should make the first case run in O(n^2) time, while the second runs in O(n).

Comment: even after removing "s=richTextBox.Lines[i]",it took that much time.I wondered just iterating over is taking so long.

Comment: See my answer for why it's still slow after removing that line.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that each line is being copied to a new string variable (str) on each loop? I'm guissing here, but you could probably verify the theory with this code

```
String s = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    string str = richTextBox.Lines[i];
    s = str;
}
```

Comment: No, that's got nothing to do with it I'm afraid. The assignment to the variable is virtually free.

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is very useful to determine **why** you're seeing performance you don't expect.

Give it a try to look at the `Lines` `get` accessor to see what it actually does each time you access it.