# is there a equivalent c++ vector::back in c#

Tags: c#

I wonder if there is a equivalent c++ vector::back in c#.
c++ vector::back is the function returns a reference to the last element of the vector.
Thank you.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246918/how-can-i-find-the-last-element-in-a-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeap, the corresponding structure in C# is the `List<T>`. You can get the last element simply writing this:

```
list.Last();
```

where `list` is a `List<T>`

**UPDATE**

One thing that we should point out is the fact that, if the list is empty, we will get an  `InvalidOperationException`.

For this reason it's may better to use the `LastOrDefault` method. So your call will be change to the following one:

```
list.LastOrDefault();
```

So for instance if list is a `List<int>` and it is empty, then list.LastOrDefault() will be 0, where 0 is the default value for an int.

For further documentation please refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Which actually works for any `IEnumerable(Of T)` which is pretty cool - just remember to add `using System.Linq` to your namespace imports.

Comment: Mind that this is not a reference in C#. I.e. a `List<int>` will not allow you to change the last member.