# How to check the last index of a for loop, if it possible?

Tags: loops, for-loop, razor, model-view-controller

Hopefully this is a easy question, i tried to do what i cound do on my own. But i can't solve the rest part.

Out for every row, i want to check if the date is heigher or lower equels to the last. But how?

As you can see yon on the image and the sample code.

[Click and see the image exsample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i9KN.png)

And the following code:

```
@using Scoutpocket.Models.Database;
@model Tuple<List<Properties>, List<SubProperties>, List<Rating>>

<div class="container">

    @foreach (var item in Model.Item1)
    {
        <br />
        <br />
        <b>
            @item.PropertiesName
        </b>

        <br />




        foreach (var item2 in item.SubProperties)
        {
            @item2.SubPropertiesName<br />

            int count = 2;
            int getLast = 1;


            foreach (var item3 in item2.rating.Where(x => x.PlayerID == 1).Take(count).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date))
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < getLast; i++)
                {
                    // Check the index of the last row, and check if the current date is lower or heighter.


                    <b>Compare date on last and newst</b>
                }

                <span>Rating ID: @item3.RatingID</span>
                <span> | </span>
                <span>Value: @item3.Value</span>
                <span> | </span>
                <span>ScoutID: @item3.ScoutID</span>

                <span> | </span>
                <span>PlayerID: @item3.PlayerID</span>

                <span> | </span>
                <span>Date: @item3.Date</span>
                <br/>
            }

        }
    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `List` types, you can easily use [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx) to get the size and do `list.Count - 1` to get last index. That will return the last element; make sure to validate the count, other wise index out of bounds might be raised. 
For instance,

```
var _dateHigh = Model.Item1.Last(); // extension methods
// same for dateLow
@foreach (var item in Model.Item1) {
    // run the code here.
}
```

If the last element changes with each iteration, then I recommend using a nested variable in the loop. We cannot help much, as you did not share the model structures, so there is very much less that we can help with.

[How can I find the last element in a List<> ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246918/how-can-i-find-the-last-element-in-a-list)