# Looking for the best way to load list view showing thumbnail pictures of a folder

Tags: c#, listview, getfiles

I've got the following code

```
files = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
   il.Images.Add(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(folder + "\\" + files[i].Name));
   lv.Items.Add(files[i].Name, i);
}
```

the code fills a System.Windows.Forms.ImageList with pictures from a jpg files.
it also creates a System.Windows.Forms.ListView where each item is associated with a picture in the imagelist.

I made the files small and tried to optimize the code. Yet I cant get under 3 seconds for 290 ~30k jpg files(or any other format).

Do you have a better way to load the list view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your code in BeginUpdate / EndUpdate calls for the ListView.

Answer (score 2):

One simple change you could make is to change this:

```
folder + "\\" + files[i].Name
```

to this:

```
files[i].FullName
```

You can also use a foreach loop instead of a for loop:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
   il.Images.Add(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
   lv.Items.Add(file.Name, i);
}
```

And a ListView can work in either bound or unbound mode. You are using unbound mode. Sometimes it is cleaner to use bound mode.

Comment: 1. I always thought that foreach is less efficient than a for loop?!
Is foreach work faster? always?

2. What should I do to get a bound mode.

3. I can't tell if the files[i].FullName made it run faster but it looks much cleaner... thanks.

Comment: After reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach, I think the loop is really fast with for or foreach... it's the loading image that I should optimize.