# Loop through cells and add to a range

Tags: vba, excel

How would I loop through cells B1 to J1 and add them to a range if they meet a certain criteria. For example.

```
Dim Range1 As Range
For i = 1 to 9
If Range("A1").Offset(1,i) meets a certain criteria Then
**Add that cell to Range1**
End If
Next i
```

I'm not sure how to approach the part of adding certain cells to Range1.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Something like this using `Union` to glue together your range

1. Please note that `For each` loops are quicker than a `For i = 1 to x` approach
2. You may well be able to use [SpecialCells](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/special-cells.htm) to determine your new range instantly (e.g. any blanks, any errors, any formulae, etc)

   ```
   Sub Test()
     Dim rng1 As Range
     Dim rng2 As Range
     Dim c As Range
     Set rng1 = Range("B1:J1")

     For Each c In rng1
       ' Add cells to rng2 if they exceed 10
       If c.Value > 10 Then
           If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
           ' Add the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc cell to our new range, rng2
           ' this is the most common outcome so place it first in the IF test (faster coding)
               Set rng2 = Union(rng2, c)
           Else
           ' the first valid cell becomes rng2
               Set rng2 = c
           End If
       End If
     Next
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: are u sure "For each loops are quicker than a For i = 1 to x approach"? i thought otherwise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach

Comment: `For Each` is faster for a range, `For I` faster for looping through a variant array

Comment: o ok. thanx for the clarification

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'Next C' or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 1):

I use this method in immediate mode when I don't want to add code to the sheet.

```
strX="": _
For Each cllX in Range( ActiveCell, Cells( Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell ).Row, ActiveCell.Column) ): _
strX=strX & iif(cllX.text="","",iif(strX="","",",")& cllX.address): _
Next: _
Range(strX).Select
```

But while that is intuitive, it only works for up to 35 to 50 cells. After that, the VBA returns an error 1004.

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

It is more robust to use the **Union** function.

```
Set rngX=ActiveCell: _
For Each cllX in Range( ActiveCell, Cells( cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell ).Row, ActiveCell.Column) ): _
Set rngX=iif( cllX.text="", rngX, Union(rngX, cllX) ): _
Next: _
rngX.Select
```

It is so short and intuitive, I just throw it away after each use.