# Union of a Range is not Working in a VBA function

Tags: vba, excel, range, union

I tried the accepted answer of [Loop through cells and add to a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320822/loop-through-cells-and-add-to-a-range) with a little bit of variation, but my Range `Arr` was never appended.

When I tried to debug through it, it was only the first range. The `Union` never worked. Why is this?

Source code:

```
Public Function VisibleRows(InRange As Range) As Range
    Dim R As Range
    Dim Arr As Range
    Dim RNdx As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer

    For RNdx = 1 To InRange.Rows.Count
        Set R = InRange(RNdx)
        If R.EntireRow.Hidden = False And R.Value2 <> "" Then
            If Arr Is Nothing Then
                Set Arr = R
            Else
                Set Arr = Union(Arr, R)
            End If
        End If
    Next RNdx
    VisibleRows = Arr
End Function
```

Comment: No need to shout. I can understand your frustration but using bold uppercase letters won't make a difference in receiving a response.

Comment: OK... My apologize! I'll go edit it!!!

Comment: If you put `Debug.Print R.Address` immediately before the line `If Arr Is Nothing Then`, you would be able to see what cells your if-statement is capturing.

Comment: change `Set R = InRange(RNdx)` to `Set R = InRange.Cells(RNdx)`, change `For RNdx = 1 To InRange.Rows.Count` to `For RNdx = 1 To InRange.Cells.Count` and `VisibleRows = Arr` to `Set VisibleRows = Arr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see a couple of problems with the code:

1. You're looping row by row, but the expression `InRange(RNdx)` takes the RNdx'th *cell* within the range - it goes horizontally first and then vertically. You probably want `InRange.Cells(RNDx, 1)`
2. Should be `Set VisibleRows = Arr`

Answer (score 2):

Your function is returning a Range Object. Range objects are assigned to a variable with the word `Set`. You are not using this word. Try this, running `TestMe()`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    VisibleRows(Range("A1:A10")).Select

End Sub

Public Function VisibleRows(InRange As Range) As Range

    Dim R As Range
    Dim Arr As Range
    Dim RNdx As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer

    For RNdx = 1 To InRange.Rows.Count
        Set R = InRange(RNdx)
        If R.EntireRow.Hidden = False And R.Value2 <> "" Then
            If Arr Is Nothing Then
                Set Arr = R
            Else
                Set Arr = Union(Arr, R)
            End If
        End If
    Next RNdx
    Set VisibleRows = Arr

End Function
```

This is the sample result from it:

[image]

Comment: That'll work on a single column, but if the range is `A1:B10` it will only highlight the first five rows if no rows are hidden and all contain a value.  As @igorsp7 has - `InRange(RNdx,1)` will check the first column of the range.