# Cell selection by cell matrix

Tags: vba

@TimWilliams if I define CellArray matrix as range then it crashes on the code to build the matrix, I followed the answer posted at the link that you have indicated https://stackoverflow.com/a/8320884/11835835

```
Dim CellsArray(3,3) As Range
For X = 0 To 2  
    For Y = 0 To 2  
        CellsArray(X, Y) = Cells(X+1,Y+1) _
        .Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)  'it crashes here run-time error 91 
    Next Y  
Next X

For K = 1 To 2  
    ActiveSheet.Union(Range(CellsArray(0, 0), CellsArray(0, K))).Select  
Next K
```

Instead it works if I define CellsArray matrix as string

```
Dim CellsArray(3,3) As String
```

but then it crashes on

```
ActiveSheet.Union(Range(CellsArray(0, 0), CellsArray(0, K))).Select
```

with run time error 438

Comment: What is Row, Column? There's no way to no what you are trying to do, but change that to `Application.Union(CellsArray...`

Comment: row column are just index calculated by x, y that I've omitted

Comment: sorry not works
`Application.Union(CellsArray...`

Comment: `Cells(X+1,Y-3)` - these two arguments need to be at least 1  Does your code even compile?

Comment: @TimWilliams the code to build the matrix works well, but next step not, when I try to select cells with the matrix elements.
If I write:
`ActiveSheet.Range(CellsArray(0, 0), CellsArray(0, 1)).Select`
it was selected a range, but I want to select non-adjacent cells.

Comment: `For X To 3` - that code works?

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range(CellsArray(0, 0) & "," & CellsArray(0, 1) & "," & CellsArray(0, 2)).Select`

Comment: `For Y To 3` I think `Cells(X+1,Y-3)` don't work, but it was approximately, `Cells(X+1,Y+3)` I think it works well. However the code for selection works well `ActiveSheet.Range(CellsArray(0, 0) & "," & CellsArray(0, 1) & "," & CellsArray(0, 2)).Select` thanks to @TimWilliams

Comment: there is a way to use this method in a for cycle? eg.
`For K = 0 to 2  
ActiveSheet.Range(CellsArray(0, K) & "," ).Select  <-- I want to cycling my matrix inside  
  
Next K`

Comment: You can use `Application.Union()` to build a range inside a loop.

Comment: don't work:
`For K = 1 To 3  
ActiveSheet.Union(CellsArray(0, K)).Select  
Next K`

Comment: even don't work: `ActiveSheet.Union(Range(CellsArray(0, K))).Select`

Comment: Did you try doing some research on how to use Union?  There are plenty of examples here on SO alone.  Eg:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320822/loop-through-cells-and-add-to-a-range

Comment: @TimWilliams if I define CellArray matrix as range then crash on the code to build the matrix

Comment: It would help to update your question to add the actual code you're having problems with, and explain exactly what happens when it runs.

Comment: @TimWilliams Now my question is updated I've updated it, have some idea?

Comment: Please fix your X and Y loops so we can tell what you're really doing. Eg:  `For Y To 3` makes no sense and will not compile

Comment: now it is a simple script that gets in a square matrix 3x3 some cells in every elements. it starts from the top of the left cell(1,1) then follow to the righ to the cell(1,3), then passes to the second row, and place the cell from the (2,1), to the cell(2,3), and finally passes to the third row getting the cell(3,1) to cell(3,3). But then when I have the method I'll modify the gotten cell. But the next step does not work, because one time I have the matrix I want to select some cell of the row of the matrix as a ricursive method with a For cycle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim CellsArray(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Range 'easier to use a 1-based array

For X = 1 To 3  
    For Y = 1 To 3  
        Set CellsArray(X, Y) = Cells(X, Y) 'Need Set here
    Next Y  
Next X

I'm not sure what you want to do here...

Dim rng As Range 
For K = 1 To 3 
    If rng is nothing then
        Set rng = CellsArray(1, 1)
    Else
        Set rng = Application.Union(rng, CellsArray(1, K)) 
    End If
Next K
rng.Select
```

Comment: In this way the selection works but not as I want, because it was selected only the cell in CellsArray(1,1) and CellsArray(1,K=3) where K is the last index of the For cycle. It is losted the central element CellArray(1,K=2). Some Idea?

Comment: Someone have any idea?

Comment: Ok in this way it works very well. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I want to ask also how I can define the `rgn` as a empty array?  I'd want to apply the above`K For` cycle inside an upper `Y For` cycle, and I need that `rgn` is empty when enter in the `K For` cycle. How I can define it ?

Comment: `Set rng = Nothing`