# Fields completion verify

Tags: c#, winforms, input, verify

I have a form with some fields on it:

```
folderNameLabel
folderTitle
folderDescription
folderCategory
```

Before the user will press `OK`, I want to check if all that fields are not `==""`. I wanted to make a function to receive an `array` as parameter and return a `bool` value, but I am not sure how to write it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool fieldsFilled = ValidateStrings(folderNameLabel.Text, 
                                        folderTitle.Text, 
                                        folderDescription.Text, 
                                        folderCategory.Text);
    if (fieldsFilled)
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    else
    {
        // Report errors
    }
}

private bool ValidateStrings(params string[] items)
{
    bool result = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length && result; i++)
        result &= !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(items[i]);

    return result;
}
```

**Question:** How do you tell the user which field he missed?

In your case, you could show a "You need to fill in all fields" message, but having only one optional field, that doesn't work anymore. This is why usually you don't do something like above.

Comment: This is what I wanted, I never known how to make a function to take an indefinite number of parameters. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's short for `a = a && b;`.

Comment: Actually, the loop can be optimized a bit - I'm modifying my answer accordingly.

Comment: Bbut why is `for` better than `foreach`?

Comment: It's not only that for arrays `for` is quicker (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach), but the loop now exits at the first occurrence of an empty string and does not check the other strings because the result would still be `false`.

Comment: Yeah, I found out already that the previous function did not work properly... You know what I mean: "does not check the other strings because the result would still be false"

Comment: I forgot to click the button :))

Comment: Should have worked fine - only looping too much. `true && !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(...) == true` as long as the string is actually not blank. If it is blank, the result comes out as `false`. After that `false && whatever == false`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16682/discussion-between-victor-barbu-and-thorsten-dittmar)

Comment: It doesn't still work properly... If I fill just one filed of the ones sent as parameters, the function returns `true`

Comment: I just tried: `Console.WriteLine(ValidateStrings("Hello", ""));` which outputs `false` and `Console.WriteLine(ValidateStrings("Hello", "World"));`, which outputs `true`. Are you doing something else wrong?

Comment: You were right, I corrected the some logical errors in my application

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool Validate(List<string> parameters)
{
   foreach(string parameter in parameters)
   {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter))
        {
            return false;
        }
   }
   return true;
}
```