# Call a method in the declaration of a foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a foreach which calls a method to get its collection.

```
 foreach(var item in GetItemDetails(item))
 {
 }
```

Visual studio doesn't complain about this, nor does Resharper, however, before I continue to use this approach, I want to reach out and check if it is a recommended approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that. The method will only be evaluated once.

It is basically:

```
using(var iter = GetItemDetails(item).GetEnumerator())
{
    while(iter.MoveNext()
    {
        var item = iter.Current;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with it.

Just two suggestions:

- If what you will put in the loop can written as a method for single items, which would make it re-usable, I would also consider the `List.ForEach(...);` method.
  Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- In case you'd be really after performance (which may happen even in C#), the for loop is usually the fastest, though less readable as less concise code:
  Info: [In .NET, which loop runs faster, 'for' or 'foreach'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach)

Comment: the times when `List.ForEach` would be preferable to regular `foreach` are *minute* - not least, keep in mind that `List<T>` has a custom `struct` iterator, making it pretty damned efficient. And re `for` vs `foreach`, that is **hugely** dependent on the scenario, and usually makes very little difference.  The difference in most *actual doing stuff* code is so small that you're essentially just profiling your profiler.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it's because English is not my mother language, but there is something I'm not sure to get in your first sentence. I did not mention .ForEach() for performance reason, just for readability. If agree about the for loop, that why I mentionned "may happen even in C#", but I have already encountered specific cases in which this kind of optimization proved to be useful.