# DataGridView.SelectedRows(WinForms) in reverse order using foreach

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to access DataGridView.SelectedRows in reverse order using foreach?

Which one is better foreach or for loop in C#?

Below code snippet giving rows in reverse order if I select mulitple rows.

```
public static DataTable GetSelectedData(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        DataTable selectedData = new DataTable();

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
        {
            selectedData.Columns.Add(col.Name, col.ValueType != null ? col.ValueType : typeof(string));
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow selectedRow in dgv.SelectedRows)
        {
            var dtRow = selectedData.NewRow();
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < dgv.Columns.Count; i1++)
                dtRow[i1] = (selectedRow.Cells[i1].Value == null ? DBNull.Value : selectedRow.Cells[i1].Value);
            selectedData.Rows.Add(dtRow);
        }

        return selectedData;
    }
```

I need an efficient way to retrieve rows in order actually in the datagridview.

Comment: _Which one is better foreach or for loop in C#?_  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach could help you.

Comment: Thanx Vidya, Can u please help in above solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options

(A) Use reverse `for` loop instead of `foreach`

```
for (int i = dgv.SelectedRows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var selectedRow = dgv.SelectedRows[i];
    // ...
}
```

(B) Create an extension method like this

```
public static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> GetSelectedRows(this DataGridView source)
    {
        for (int i = source.SelectedRows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            yield return source.SelectedRows[i];
    }
}
```

and use it as follows

```
foreach (var selectedRow in dgv.GetSelectedRows())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, I am looking for solution using foreach.. 
If I use for loop here, does it impact performance of code?

Comment: @VikrantMishra Actually the `for` loop is faster than `foreach`. Option (B) is provided for your convinience - to use the "familiar" `foreach` when needed. And btw, what do you mean by `I'm looking for a solution using foreach"? If you are looking for a `standard` solution, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok..thanks a lot @lvanStoev.. using for loop I already implemented that.. 
I am looking for, if its possible through foreach.. Thanks