# optimizing the if and foreach for nullchecks

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

Anyway to optimize this code for null checks?

```
if (objA != null && objA .Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var child in objA )
                {
                    if (child.Any != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var a in child.Any)
                        {
                            if (a.Name.ToLower() == "code")
                            {
                                //some code
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can safely lose `objA.Length > 0`, as the `foreach` loop will effectively duplicate it. Not seeing anything else.

Comment: @glenebob: Ok sure

Comment: What is the type of `objA`? Please show us the definition of your `Any` property.

Comment: @mjwills: objA is an array of objectA .

Comment: `foreach (var a in objA?.SelectMany(z => z?.Any).Where(y => y?.Name?.ToLower() == "code") ?? Enumerable.Empty<YourTypeHere>())` would likely work.

Comment: Optimisation wise, what is your aim? Do you want clarity? Performance? Brevity? Something else?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use the C# 6 null condition `?` operator . Here is some psuedo code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objA?.Length; i++)
{
    ExecuteCode(objA[i]?.Any);
}
```

...

```
static void ExecuteCode(YourTypeHere[] children)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < children?.Length; i++)
    {
        if (children[i]?.Name?.ToLower() == "code")
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

Using a for loop is faster than a foreach: [In .NET, which loop runs faster, 'for' or 'foreach'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach). Both loops are slightly faster than Linq.