# Add value to array in C#

Tags: c#

Hello I'm just starting in c # and am practicing with arrays, my question is how I can add a name called "steve" the array of this code:

```
    string[] names = new string[] {"Matt", "Joanne", "Robert"};

    foreach (string i in names)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(i + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you mean append? (Arrays are not resizable.) Or just change one of them? (names[0] = "steve";)

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: Add `, "Steve"`.  Too obvious perhaps.

Comment: If you want to add things to an array, why not use a `List`?

Comment: You more want a `List<string>` instead of an array. Arrays are fixed size. You would have to create a new array and copy all over, thats not what you really want.

Comment: what I want is to add a new one, no change other

Comment: Resizing Arrays - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Steve That method's name is a misnomer.  It *never* resizes the array.  It simply creates a new array of the larger size.  That is noticeably different from actually resizing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding values to a C# array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202813/adding-values-to-a-c-sharp-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays don't play well with this idea. Usually, people use List for this kind of thing.

```
List<string> names = new List<string> {"Matt", "Joanne", "Robert"};

names.Add("Steve");

foreach (string i in names)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(i + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [resize an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), however its probably better to just use a list if you need a collection who's size changes.

Note that resizing an array actually just creates a new array of the size you want behind the scenes and copies over all the data

Answer (score 2):

You can't add elements to an array once the array has been created. You can:

- Add the element before the array has been created as a literal:

  ```
  string[] names = new string[] {"Matt", "Joanne", "Robert", "Steve", "Another name", "Tons of other names"};
  ```
- Or you can use a collection that allows you to add elements after it has been created such as a `List`. To use a `List` instead of array, make sure you have the following directive `using System.Collections.Generic` at the top of your main file (should be included by default). Now you can do:

  ```
  List<string> names = new List<string> {"Matt", "Joanne", "Robert"};
  names.Add("Steve");
  names.Add("Another one");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Although [you can expand .NET arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in a situation like this you would be better off with a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> {"Matt", "Joanne", "Robert"};
```

Now you can add a new name to `names` by calling `Add`:

```
names.Add("Steve");
```

Note: rather than using `AppendText` in a loop, you could use `string.Join`, like this:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(names.Join(Environment.NewLine, names));
```

Answer (score 1):

To add the Item to the array, using the code you provided, you can do this:

```
string[] names = new string[] { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };

Array.Resize(ref names, names.Length + 1);
names[names.Length - 1] = "Steve";

foreach (string i in names)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(i + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Consider using this code instead, that uses List:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };
names.Add("Steve");     // Add a new entry
richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, names));
```

Answer (score 0):

The array has a fix size. At first you've created that with three elements, so it will have three elements. You can modify any element so:

```
names[index] = "value";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list from an Array by writting:

```
List<string> list = names.OfType<string>().ToList();
```

and then continue from there as the others mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

Example for resizing your array:

```
string[] names = { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };
Array.Resize(ref names, names.Length + 1);
names[names.Length - 1] = "Steve";
```

Steve has given the proper reference above.

Comment: Tony, I guess I was 22 minutes distracted :-)