# How to add values to Named Array of Class Type?

Tags: c#

I have a Array `Configuration[]` wrapped with `ConfigurationArray` class, how I can add values to array using `ConfigurationArray`.

```
public class ConfigurationArray
{
    [DataMember(Name = "configurations")]
    public Configuration[] Configurations { get; set; }
}

public class Configuration
{        
    [DataMember(Name = "configurationType")]
    public string ConfigurationType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "configurationValue")]
    public string ConfigurationValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Having a `ConfigurationArray` class in which itself exposes a `Configuration` array feels a little weird to me. Instead of wrapping the array, I'd simply expose a `List<Configuration>` via whoever needs such a list.

Comment: Agree with @YuvalItzchakov or you could inherent from `Collection<Configuration>` if you need to provide additional functionality for the collection but i'd still recommend changing the class name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding values to a C# array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202813/adding-values-to-a-c-sharp-array)

Answer (score 8):

You can't. An array has a fixed size, so the only thing you can do in order to add one to the array, is to 'expand the array' by creating a new one with a bigger size than the previous one and copy all items over.

The best option you have is to use a `List<Configuration>` instead of `Configuration[]`, which is capable of sizing itself.

Comment: I have this below json what type we can use this one in c#{"configurations":[{"configurationType":"CPC","configurationValue":2501},{"configurationType":"WLK","configurationValue":false},{"configurationType":"RDM","configurationValue":100},{"configurationType":"BCK","configurationValue":20}]}