# rewriting list of strings to a struct array is not working - indexing error

Tags: c#, struct

I defined an array player using `struct igralec` that accepts one string and one integer. I need array `player` in other functions too because i have to manipulate with the data inside.

However, if I try to run the whole code I get an error in a last for loop at line

**player[i].Name = myList[i];**

already at first index `i`.

The error says: *An unhandled exception of type "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" occured in game.exe*.

```
igralec[] player { get; set; }

public struct igralec
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Points;
        public igralec( string ime, int tocke)
        {
            Name = ime;
            Points = tocke;
        }
    }

    public void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> myList = new List<string>();
            //declaring a list of strings to which all the player names are copied
            for (int i = 0; i < PlayersList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                PlayersList.Items[i].Selected = true; //marking the items from the list as selected
            }
            foreach (ListViewItem Item in PlayersList.SelectedItems)
            {
                myList.Add(Item.Text.ToString()); //add to list all selected items
            }
            if (PlayersList.Items.Count != 0 && SteviloTock.SelectedItem != null) {
                //collect the data in struct vector so I can use it outside this function
                player = new igralec[] { };
                //rewrite the array so you can use it outside the function
                for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
                {
                    player[i].Name = myList[i];
                    player[i].Points = StTock;
                }
            }
        }
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: do this player = new igralec[myList.Count] { };

Comment: At `player = new igralec[] { };` you're initializing `player` to be an array of `igralec` of size 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a new array `player = new igralec[] { };` then immediately try to access the first element in the array `i = 0`, `player[i].Name = myList[i];`

`player[0]` doesn't exist yet (empty array) so the  `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` is thrown. You need to add a new element to the player collection instead.

You could consider using a List if you don't know the array size when creating the collection, as suggested in [Adding values to a C# array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202813/adding-values-to-a-c-sharp-array):

```
List<igralec> igralecList = new List<igralec>();
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    igralecList.Add(new igralec(myList[i], StTock));
}

// You can convert it back to an array if you would like to
igralec[] igralecArray = igralecList.ToArray();
```

Or with a lambda expression (as suggested by [Andrei Olariu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3819485/andrei-olariu)):

```
player = myList.Select(i => new igralec(i, StTock)).ToArray();
```

Comment: How does one add elements to an empty array?

Comment: @Alex, that can be done cleaner with a lambda: `player = myList.Select(i => new igralec(i, StTock)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, it's because your array doesn't have a size.

You could also try this:

```
player = myList.Select(i => new igralec(i, StTock)).ToArray();
```

Instead of this:

```
//collect the data in struct vector so I can use it outside this function
player = new igralec[] { };
//rewrite the array so you can use it outside the function
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    player[i].Name = myList[i];
    player[i].Points = StTock;
}
```