# Insert string value to object array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have below array of type object

```
object[] myarray = new object[] { "1", "Success"};
```

I want to insert string value at first position in myarray is there any method 
to do this result should be like below:

I want array like below

```
object[] myarray = new object[] { "logFile","1", "Success"};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding values to a C# array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202813/adding-values-to-a-c-sharp-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to stick with the array:

```
myarray = new object[]{"logFile"}.Concat(myarray).ToArray();
```

The classic, non-LINQ (and most efficient) way is to use `Array.Copy`:

```
var newArray = new object[myarray.Length + 1];
newArray[0] = "logFile";
Array.Copy(myarray, 0, newArray, 1, myarray.Length);
// myarray = newArray;
```

Comment: Or the other way round: `myarray = myarray.Concat(new object[] {"logFile"}).ToArray();`.

Comment: @Tim your solution is good but is complicated for a beginner  :)

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel Using (basic) Linq is not complicated at all. This is simply a function that merges 2 arrays together, converting to a list and then inserting sounds much more complicated in my opinion.

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel; you find the LINQ way complicated? Then look at the classic way using `Array.Copy` i have asdded now ;-)

Comment: Ok I know  this is the main Goal  of LINQ do more with less code but the OP will escape there is  a built in class for this

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm  not saying is complicated for me I enjoy LINQ and the great idea behind it  but for sake of KISS principle :)

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to `List<string>` which can grow dynamically

```
  List<string> myArray= new List<string> { "1", "Success"};
```

and use [List.Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Collections.Generic.List%601.Insert);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

```
myArray.Insert(0,"LogFile");
```

From  MSDN how List.Insert works

*If Count already equals Capacity, the capacity of the List is increased by automatically reallocating the internal array, and the existing elements are copied to the new array before the new element is added.
If index is equal to Count, item is added to the end of List.*

Comment: what exception you got

Comment: yes there is an insert https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Collections.Generic.List%601.Insert);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Comment: You should rename `myArray` to `myList` ... the names are pretty confusing when you have a List named `myArray`. @John make sure that you call the Insert method on a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` and not an array.

Comment: @IanH. yes you are right but just for sake of simplicity I named it array

Comment: List<string> myArray1 = File.ReadAllLines(ScriptPath + "\\executionresult.txt");

Comment: @John try this: `List<string> myArray1 = File.ReadAllLines(ScriptPath + "\\executionresult.txt").ToList();`. You have to convert the array to a list in order to save it as such.

Comment: @John what is your question ?

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel He is **saving the array into a list variable**.

Comment: `yes you are right but just for sake of simplicity I named it array` For the sake of simplicity I could call my cat a dog. But that isn't helpful. It isn't a dog.

Comment: Thanks Brahim for your answer