# Add specific images to FileInfo[]

Tags: c#, image, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I have a FileInfo object that receives all images from a directory:-

```
string Path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/TempImages/");
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Path);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
```

This works fine and gets all the images from the directory. However, I only want to get specific images from the directory which I have in a list (ImagesToShow):-

```
string Path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/TempDocs/");
foreach (var image in ImagesToShow)
{
  //How do I add all image.imageName to the FileInfo[] object?
}
```

Comment: use a `List<FileInfo>` and `AddRange`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding values to a C# array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202813/adding-values-to-a-c-sharp-array)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with a List<>

```
      var AllDocs = //List of image names

      string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/TempImages/");
      List<FileInfo> filelist = new List<FileInfo>();
      foreach (var item in AllDocs)
      {
         filelist.Add(new FileInfo(path + item.ImageName));
      }
```

Then convert to array if needed

```
      FileInfo[] newfiles = filelist.ToArray();
```