# How to add an item to Vector3 after it has been created

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First I create the Vector3:

```
Vector3[] foo = {
    1, 2, 3
}
```

Later in my code, I need to add a new item to `foo`, but I can't find a way to do this.

I have tried `foo.Add(4)`, but I get the error:
*Vector3 does not contain a definition for Add*

I want foo to end up as `1, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: Use a list object List<Vector3> foo = new List<Vector3>() { 1,2,3};

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding values to a C# array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202813/adding-values-to-a-c-sharp-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list instead of an Array. It will give you more options to add and remove items.

```
List<Vector3> yourList = new List<Vector3>() { 1,2,3};
yourList.Add(4); // Add a new element
yourList.Add(5); // Add a new element
yourList.Remove(5); // Remove an element.
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the List into a Vector3 Array? I need to use it as the vertices for a mesh.