# How to add elements from foreach into array

Tags: c#, arrays

Hi I'm making a simple web scraping solution that gets several titles of different articles and I want to save all the extracted titles (strings) into an array from a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@class='entry__title']"))
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
}
```

Is there a specific way to? I been looking in the documents but seems like I just can't make it work..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding values to a C# array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202813/adding-values-to-a-c-sharp-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just replicate what you have mentioned, use linq

```
var arraydata = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@class='entry__title']")).Select(t=>t.InnerText).ToArray();
```

Comment: How does that exactly work? sorry it's my first time using scraping method

Comment: This has nothing to do with scraping. You question is how to save the text into array.  That's what you were looking for. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/

Comment: oh i see now, thank you!

Comment: Please accept the answer when it is what you are looking for..