# Set a fixed size ArrayList

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist, size

someone knows if it's possible create a fixed size ArrayList? Or I have to use necessarily an array?

I try with this

```
Dim array As ArrayList

array = New ArrayList(10)
```

and

```
array.Capacity = 10
```

But I can add more than 10 items, and it doesn 't show me any kind of error how I expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `Array` this size will not change unless you explicitly code it to.

```
Dim myArray(9) As String 'or whatever object you need Integer, etc.
```

Note that specifying 9 will create 0-9 i.e. 10 items in your array

([ArrayLists are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823684/dont-use-arraylist) in many many ways so don't use them)

Answer (score 0):

`Capacity` of ArrayList tells **the maximum number of items** `ArrayList` can currently hold. `Capacity` will be **increased automatically** at run time when more items are added in the `ArrayList`.

For fixed size, use `Array` as mentioned below:

```
Dim intArray(9) As Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to store different types in your collection you can use;

```
Dim myArray(5) As Object
```

If you wanted to read them back as the type you put them in as you would have to convert their type back what they were originally.

I do not recommend this as an approach. If you want to do this then I suggest you create a custom object such as a class or [structures](http://www.dotnetperls.com/structure) that will contain properties for each of the values you wish to set.