# What are the general differences in C# collections, and what is the underlying data structure?

Tags: c#, collections, computer-science

Just want a brief overview of the differences of c#'s collection types, and what would the underlying data structure be for each?

e.g. string[], ArrayList, Array, List, and hashes, sets, etc.

I know of linked lists, binary trees (in general), but would be interested to know (at a high level) what advantages each has etc.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128636/net-data-structures-arraylist-list-hashtable-dictionary-sortedlist-sortedd

Comment: Underneith all collections is array. So for e.g. List<int> has array of int underneith.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN link on collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

String[] would just be a straight string array. ArrayList adds the ability to Add() without having a size for the array up front, but loses strong typing. List adds strong typing. A Hash is a key value pair. that si a start.