# Dictionary, List or Array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, dictionary

I'm writing a service where performance is essential, and I'm not sure what is the fastest thing. I have a few Objects (50-200) which each have an ID in them (ints, e.g. 84397 or 23845). Would it be faster to have a Dictionary, a List of KeyValue Pairs or a List with the indexes set to the IDs with the rest having null values or an array with the same idea?

Comment: Have you tried to run a simple test application?

Comment: I've started it, but I thought asking would be more efficient (for future askers and me).

Comment: Which operations you have to do with those objects? Search by key? Search for values? Many inserts? Removing keys?

Comment: In the case you're using arrays - what is the maximum ID you have? How ofter you'll increase array size?

Comment: Read value by key (random times), update value by key (every second), a few inserts (every few seconds). Maximum ID is not fixed.

Comment: Faster wrt to what? Faster lookup? Removal? Addition? Updation? Insertion? Enumeration? Lesser memory overhead so that other programs run smoother? Faster to write? Sorry voting to close.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on which operation you want to execute. Let's assume that you want to **find an object with a given ID**.

- The *huge array* approach is fastest: Accessing `myArray[84397]` is a constant-time operation **O(1)**. Of course, this approach requires the most memory.
- The *dictionary* is almost as fast but requires less memory, since it uses a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) internally.
- The *list of pairs* approach is the slowest, since you might have to traverse the whole list to find your entry, which yields **O(n)** complexity.

Thus, in your situation, I would choose the dictionary, unless the marginally better performance of the huge array is really relevant in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll use the dictionary (assuming marginally means something like 1ms faster).

Comment: You wrote "dictionary requires less memory" - didn't you mean to write it requires MORE memory, since it uses a hash table internally?

Comment: @BornToCode: It requires less memory than the previous option, the huge array. The huge array requires *maximumID* storage places, whereas the dictionary only requires around *someConstant*numberOfElements* storage places.

Answer (score 8):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses a hash table internally so I think it would be the fastest one.

Comment: +1 This is precisely why `Dictionary` exists.

Comment: Would a HashTable itself be better?

Comment: @SBoss - The generic dictionary does not use a `HashTable` internally, so no.  A `HashTable` is considerably slower when you use ValueTypes, like you plan on doing with your `int`.

Comment: A `Dictionary<K,V>` uses a hash table, but does not use the `HashTable` class.

Comment: @Gabe - Yes.  I now realize I wasn't clear about that.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @SBoss Performance for both HashTable and Dictionary would be very similar but there is one major difference ` Dictionary is a generic type, Hashtable is not. That means you get type safety with Dictionary, because you can't insert any random object into it, and you don't have to cast the values you take out.`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, you can't just [completely change someone's post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4247992). Make your own answer if you have one.

Answer (score 2):

[Dictionary versus List Lookup time](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time)

Also, for a more detailed explaination of the different collections, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128636/-net-data-structures-arraylist-list-hashtable-dictionary-sortedlist-sortedd).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hashtables as well. Dictionary internally using it anyway. 
but dictionary has an advantage that it is a GENERIC type which gives you type safety.

here is different thread 
[Dictionary Vs HashTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-dictionary-is-preferred-over-hashtable-in-c)
I hope it helps you decide.

Praveen