# If condition bash alike - check and assignment

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am implementing A* algorithm and I am stuck with the following piece of pseudo code :

```
 if neighbor not in openset or tentative_g_score <= g_score[neighbor] 
     came_from[neighbor] := current
     g_score[neighbor] := tentative_g_score
     f_score[neighbor] := g_score[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)
     if neighbor not in openset
         add neighbor to openset
```

I want to optimize the openset checking so that I won't check if a node is openset twice in one algorithm pass.

I know that in bash there is something like :

```
if(( false == openedList_.ContainsNodeXY(n.X, n.Y)) && 
     InOpenSet = false ){ .... }
```

With this I would have information about node being in or not in the openset.

How can I do this in C# ?

**EDIT** 
`openList_` is a List ( I have to have it sorted ) so it can't be a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HashSet<T>` object in C# for this.  HashSet will quickly be able to tell you if an object is a member of the Set.

[HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) has `Add` and `Contains` methods.

---

Based on your comment you probably want SortedList.  It will not be faster, HashSet is O(1) in most cases.  SortedList will be O(n) on insert.  SortedList also has `Contains` (since they both implement IDictionary).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/128754/215752) helpful answer.

Comment: 1. I need this to be a List (I appropriately sort it) 2. I thought that I can do it additional bool - as I think this will be faster than (even! HashSet) check

Answer (score 0):

I think what A* requires is a priority queue that also supports fast `Contains`. `SortedSet<T>` is this class. As far as I understand it it is a Red-Black-Tree.

Warning: Don't use the `SortedList<T>` classes from the BCL. It is legacy stuff based on a horrible `O(n^2)` algorithm.